# Bison and Flex code works every other time

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am creating a basic Lisp interpreter by utilizing Bison and Flex, so as of now I am trying to make an infix adder that also reads a set of parenthesis. For some reason my code only seems to work every other time

lisp.l

```
 %option noyywrap
%{
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "lisp.tab.h"
//  #include "lisp.h"
    #include <string.h>
    #define YYSTYPE double

    #define YY_DECL int yylex()
%}

%%

[ \t]    ;  {/* eat up whitespace */}
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?   {yylval.dval = atof(yytext); return DOUBLE;}
"+"             {return ADD; }
"-"         {return SUB; }
"/"         {return DIVIDE; }
"*"         {return MULTIPLY; }
"let"           {return LET;}
"print"         {return PRINT;}
"EQ"            {return EQUAL;}
"LT"            {return LESSTHAN;}
"LE"            {return LESSTHANEQUAL;}
"GT"            {return GREATERTHAN;}
"GE"            {return GREATERTHANEQUAL;}
"NE"            {return NOTEQUAL;}
"if"            {return IF;}
";"             {return IGNORE;}
[a-zA-Z]+       {return identifier;}
"("         {return LEFTPAR;}
")"         {return RIGHTPAR;}


%%
```

lisp.y

```
%{


    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
//  #include <map>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "lisp.tab.h"


//  static std::map<std::string, double> symbolsMap;

//  double symbolValMap(std::string symbol);
//  void updateSymbolValMap(std::string symbol, double val);

    extern int yylex();

    extern FILE* yyin;

    extern int yyparse();

    void yyerror(const char* msg);
%}

%union {
    double dval;
}
%token<dval> DOUBLE
%token<id> identifier
%token LET PRINT EQUAL LESSTHAN LESSTHANEQUAL GREATERTHAN GREATERTHANEQUAL
%token NOTEQUAL IF IGNORE LEFTPAR RIGHTPAR MULTIPLY DIVIDE SUB ADD


%type<dval> mixed_expression
%type<id> varName

%left SUB ADD MULTIPLY DIVIDE

%start program


%%
program:
    | program line
    ;

line: '\n'
    | mixed_expression '\n'   {printf("\tResult: %f\n", $1);}
    | '(stop)\n'          {printf("bye!\n"); exit(0); }
    ;

mixed_expression: DOUBLE        {$$ = $1;}
    | LEFTPAR ADD  mixed_expression mixed_expression RIGHTPAR     {$$ = $3 + $4; printf("Result: %g","%1f", $$);}
    | LEFTPAR SUB  mixed_expression mixed_expression RIGHTPAR     { $$ = $3 - $4; }
    | LEFTPAR MULTIPLY mixed_expression mixed_expression RIGHTPAR {$$ = $3 * $4;}
    | LEFTPAR DIVIDE mixed_expression mixed_expression RIGHTPAR   {$$ = $3 / $4;}
    | LEFTPAR  mixed_expression RIGHTPAR                { $$ = $2; }
    ;


%%
int main() {
    yyin = stdin;
    do { 
        yyparse();
    } while(!feof(yyin));
    return 0;
}
/*void updateSymbolValMap(std::string symbol, double val)
{
//  symbolsMap[symbol] = val;
}
double symbolValMap(std::string symbol)
{
// return symbolsMap[symbol];
    return 0;
}*/
void yyerror(char const* msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", msg);
    yyparse();
}
```

When I run the code and pass in arguments the following is outputted:

```
(- 4 5)
Result: -1
(* 8 9)
Parse error: syntax error
Parse error: syntax error
Parse error: syntax error
Parse error: syntax error
```

Makefile

```
all = lisp

lisp.tab.c lisp.tab.h: lisp.y
    bison -d lisp.y

lex.yy.c: lisp.l lisp.tab.h
    flex lisp.l

lisp:   lex.yy.c lisp.tab.c lisp.tab.h
    gcc lisp.tab.c lex.yy.c -lm -o lisp

clean:
    rm lisp lisp.tab.c lex.yy.c lisp.tab.h
```

No matter what, every other time I am given a parse error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It "works" exactly once, not "every other time". Right? It won' t work on the third line either. (Out of curiosity, why do you insist that expressions be separated by newline characters? Lisp doesn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work:

```
line: '\n'
    | mixed_expression '\n'   {printf("\tResult: %f\n", $1);}
```

It is necessary that your lexical analyser return the token `\n`. But your lexical analyser never does that. In fact, a newline character does not match any rule in your lexical analyser, so it will execute the [default action](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html#Matching) (see the third paragraph), which is to simply print the unmatched character to standard output and continue looking for a token, without passing anything to the parser.

Moreover, this cannot work at all:

```
   | '(stop)\n'          {printf("bye!\n"); exit(0); }
```

because `'(stop)\n'` is not a C character literal and the lexical analyser will certainly not be able to return it. I suspect that you will have received a warning from lex about this. Changing the symbol to `"(stop)\n"` will silence the warning, but it will still not result in a token which can be returned from the lexical analyser.

There are a number of other issues, including the fact that you use a semantic value tag (`<id>`) which does not appear in your `%union` declaration, and you declare it the type of a non-terminal (`varName`) which is not defined. Also, the precedence declaration (`%left SUB ADD MULTIPLY DIVIDE`) is pointless since those tokens do not enter into shift-reduce conflicts.